# Removing Value From Numpy Array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I am creating a game that requires the player to know the closest food item.

instead of iterating through every food item every step, to which their may be (1000+) I have separated my room into a grid.

the grid stores all abject ID's in a cell and the search algorithm looks in the cells nearest the player to find the closest one.

Problem is: when the player moves to a new cell, I need to update the grid to reflect that.

I am having issues removing the player from their past cell once they move to a new one.

the update function below executes once the player has entered a new cell.

this function checks if the player ID appears in the past cell, deletes it if it does. (not working)

it then updates the cell to the current one.

and lastly writes the player ID in the new cell.

```
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
cell_size = 128

grid = np.empty((int(math.ceil(display_width/cell_size)),int(math.ceil(display_height/cell_size)),1),object)

def update(self):
    #Removes self from Grid Data
    if id(self) in grid[self.cell_x,self.cell_y]:
        np.delete(grid[self.cell_x,self.cell_y] ,np.argwhere(grid[self.cell_x,self.cell_y] == id(self)))

    #updates current cell
    self.cell_x = int(math.ceil(self.x // 128))
    self.cell_y = int(math.ceil(self.y // 128))

    #writes new grid data
    grid[self.cell_x,self.cell_y,0] = np.append(grid[self.cell_x,self.cell_y,0],id(self))
    print(grid)
```

the result is the object appearing in multiple cells at the same time as their past cell position is not clearing as desired.

Comment: `grid` appears to be initialed as a (n,m,1) object dtype array.  Why the 3rd, size 1, dimension. Without that you could omit the 0 index.   Initially it contains `None` values.  `np.delete` does not work in-place.  It makes a brand new array.  Uses object dtype array doesn't save you any time.  Iteration and indexing of a list of lists is usually faster.

Comment: Your question will be clearer if you create and display a small grid, and show the kinds of changes you want and what ones if get (if any).  If you look at other SO answers you'll see they almost always include a working example.  We want to demonstrate that the answer works, and verify that it is behaving as you expect.  See the help for [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html has the manual.

numpy.delete() does not delete in place but returns a copy with the specified row or column deleted.

Your current code does not assign the result of delete() to the grid cell. Just add the missing assignment.